# Azure AD - homepage value deleted when adjusting app's Required Permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created a registered app in Azure AD, and via the portal when I modify API Access\Required Permissions (add/change, for example), the Home Page URL back on the properties tab of the registered app is now blank. I’ve verified this by looking at the homepage field value in PowerShell. I can add the value back with no problem ... but I'm confused as to why this value disappears?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and Microsoft will have a fix deployed soon. Thank you for reporting.